# Facebook Album Picture using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: silverlight, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm tring to get an album picture from facebook using the facebook C# SDK within Silverlight app with the following code:

```
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(this.Profile.AccessToken);
        client.GetAsync(string.Format("/{0}/picture?type=small", this.ID));
        client.GetCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            dynamic result = e;
        };
```

Where this.ID is the ID of the album, but I get this error:
   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Line 1, position 1.
from the DeserializeObject method in the JsonSerializer. The problem is that facebook does'n return json data with the imge uri or something like this, but they actually return the image itself in a binary data. Anybody has any idea how I can handle this result or just get Uri to the image?
I have a workaround for this using this code:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?access_token={1}", this.ID, this.Profile.AccessToken));
        request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
        {
            using (var response = ((WebRequest)ar.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(ar))
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    this.Picture = new BitmapImage(new Uri(response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri));
                }
                );
            }
        }, request);
```

But I really wanted to use only Facebook C# SDK for getting the data.

Here is the solution that I'm going to use:

```
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(this.Profile.AccessToken);
        client.QueryAsync(String.Format("SELECT src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE object_id={0})", this.ID));
        client.GetCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            dynamic result = e.GetResultData();

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.Picture = result[0].src_small);
        };
```

Comment: Facebook documentations says the the 'picture' connection of the 'album' node returns _An HTTP 302 with the URL of the album's cover picture._ Which is kind of strange and I'm really wondering what is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: I think I found an acceptable solution for my problem. I'll just use FQL instead of Graph API. This will do the job: 
`FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(this.Profile.AccessToken); client.QueryAsync(String.Format("SELECT src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE object_id={0})", this.ID)); client.GetCompleted += (s, e) => { dynamic result = e.GetResultData(); Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.Picture = result[0].src_small); };`

Comment: You should really break out the solution and post it as an answer to (your own) question, and mark it as the correct answer. That way it will be much clearer.

Comment: @Magnus Johansson I sure will and I initially tried to do this, but it seems that I'm still a new user and I'm unable to post a solution to my own question within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an acceptable solution for my problem. I'll just use FQL instead of Graph API. This will do the job:

```
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(this.Profile.AccessToken);
        client.QueryAsync(String.Format("SELECT src_small, src_big, src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE object_id={0})", this.ID));
        client.GetCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            dynamic result = e.GetResultData();

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.Picture = result[0].src_small);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. Wanted to use Facebook C# SDK only as well.
Solved it like this:

```
FacebookClient facebookAlbumClient = new FacebookClient(_albumAccessToken);
dynamic facebookAlbumCover = facebookAlbumClient.Get(string.Format("/{0}?fields=picture&type=thumbnail", (string)facebookAlbum["id"]));
```

This way you are getting the json array and not the picture