# Get photo from album to show in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

I use this code, but I can't view a picture.

```
public class ImgInfo
{
    public string img { get; set; }
}

private void ShowPictures()
{
    List<ImgInfo> images = new List<ImgInfo>();
    dynamic pictures = _fb.Get((selectedAlbum.id + "/photos"));
    foreach (dynamic pic in pictures.data)
    {
        ImgInfo imginfo = new ImgInfo() { img = pic["picture"]};
        images.Add(imginfo);
    }

    ImageGridView.ItemsSource = images;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ImageGridView" BorderThickness="0">
```

Comment: I don't know where is that ShowPictures() method called, but I guess that the first problem is images is deleted at the end of the method.
Besides, you might want to look a bit into INotifyPropertyChanged interface and binding concepts, as these are much better styles than that.
The biggest issue I see here is that nowhere in your code is stated that listbox should show images and not, say, strings.
Look more at the listbox documentation to define it better in your XAML

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706225/facebook-album-picture-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk